# What is the difference between signal and middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django

I dont understand what is the difference between this two function in Django.

Both is doing something before or after request/response.

Just like context switch or decorator.

Can anyone tell me how to use this two Django function properly.

Answer (score 2):

According to Django documentation:

Signals:

Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. ***In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place.*** They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

Middlewares:

Middleware ***is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing.*** It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output.

**TLDR;**

- Signals are used to dispatch an information that will be listened by receivers, for example executing some code before saving something into the database or execute some code after an email was sent.
- Middlewares are classes that hook into HTTP request/responses.

Comment: so that mean if I register a signal, I can send signal whenever I want.

Comment: But I register a middleware in WSGI, it just like a decorator?

Comment: That let me so confused because there are default signal  before/after response in Django.

Comment: One more question, Signal is multi threading ,multi processing or asyncio execution?

Comment: No, signals are single threaded and sync execution, as far as I know Django does not have multi threading, multiprocessing or asyncio natively yet.

Comment: Signals can be used anywhere you want, including before/after HTTP requests.

Comment: As I know, If you want to exec at "same" time, there are three different approach is m-threading, m-processing, coroutine.